# Powershell - Find instances without a tag associated

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I have spent a long time on this getting nowhere and cannot find an answer on the web.

I am looking for a PowerShell script that will return EC2 Instances without tag called 'backup' associated with it.

Each Backup tag has a value but right now I am just looking for instances which do not have the tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your attempt of trying to get the info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the EC2 Instance objects without a tag named `Backup` in a specific region:

```
Import-Module AWSPowershell
$instances = (Get-EC2Instance -Region $region -Credential $cred).Instances
$EC2Tags = Get-EC2Tag -Region $region -Credential $cred | 
    Where {$_.Key -eq 'Backup' -and $_.ResourceType -EQ 'Instance'}

$instances | Where {$_.InstanceID -NotIn $EC2Tags.ResourceID}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks this is just what I need